# Raspberry Pi newcomer questions

Tags: raspbian, usb, hardware

I have the Raspberry Pi model b+ 512mb and 8gbs noobs edition. I was wondering what basic programs i should install like a way to eject usbs. I am mostly used to windows but i do like using ubuntu also. Also its very slow and i know its because i havent added anything but i wanted to know if there was a way to increase my speed. Also some extra part suggestions are welcome since im gonna be buying a case also.

Answer (score 3):

You can safely remove a flash drive by unmounting it.  This is performed with the `umount` command.  If you're using the graphical interface, right clicking on the drive and selecting unmount will accomplish the same thing.

As far as speeding up the device goes, I've found that the default clock speed is rather slow.  I keep mine overclocked to 900Mhz.  This can be accomplished by running the command `sudo raspi-config` and selecting option 7.  You can try high or turbo if you feel the inclination, but I would start slower and ramp it up carefully.

Answer (score 2):

you can unmount something with the button next to the time at the top of the screen and you can speed up the raspberry pi by making sure there arent too many programs in the background and make sure you are using the chromium web browser with u block origin ad blocker installed and when the raspberry pi overheats it slows down to stop it so i highly recommend that you put a heatsink on the cpu to stop this.

Also make sure to use a class 10 sd card from a good brand like sandisk and try using a newer raspberry pi like the raspberry pi 3 b+ but the raspberry pi 4 might be out soon so i recommend waiting for it.